# Set pixel-accuracy text in Android

Tags: java, android, pixel

I want to know if it's possible to set a `textView` with pixel-accuracy using Android. In my case, I have this background image, lets say I know exactly in which pixel I want to put my text, is this possible? Another question: will the image keep the same pixel location which every mobile screen?

Comment: @DerGolem it is actually answer :)

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, as suggested by @EugenMartynov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better prepare your background images **WITH the text** already in them.
And, **no**, you have to prepare `different images for different screen densities`.
And for different resolutions as well.
Since the text will stay in its position (it's only `part of the image`, so it is just **colored pixels**), but it will be horribly stretched.

Comment: How I know which option is clicked by an user in my program?

Comment: ... Option? Weren't we talking about `TextView`s? To provide **options** you have a plethora of choices: `RadioButton`s, `CheckBox`es, `Spinner`s, `ListView`s, `GridView`s, ...

Comment: Yes, I already know that. But, suppose I have four titles in my image, how I know which was pressed?

Comment: This is **another question**. Anyway, TextViews are clickable. And so they can react as Buttons to a Click event.

Comment: I'm confident you already know how to distinguish among different Buttons  (or other Views) clicks.

Comment: I know that. My point is, you have an image with four titles, and suppose the user press the first title or the second title, or whichever, it doesn't matter. How I know which one was pressed? I'm guessing I need to place bigger buttons that in more or less accuracy way manage which title was pressed.

Comment: No. I guess that instead you need to use a `RadioGroup` holding the background image and then put inside it 4 `Radiobuttons` **without** the button image, only the text. This way you will simulate a common  background and the 4 TextViews, but you can also use **weights**, since the `RadioGroup inherits from LinearLayout`. So to have the 4 Radiobuttons the same width or height (let's say all 25%). And you don't have to get mad for pixels.